# Biblatex-apa not replacing ampersand for citations and references with Spanish options

Tags: biblatex, babel, apa-style

I have read that the `spanish-apa.lbx` file contains the command `\setcounter{smartand}{0}` to prevent the ampersand from showing up and uses `y` instead. However, I can't seem to manage to get this right when using `\parencite`, or actually any other citation for more than one author while using the Spanish `biblatex-apa` style.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{Guy2010,
Author = {Some Guy and Another Dude},
Publisher = {A Publisher},
Title = {A reference book to everything},
Year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
Localisation is a headache. \parencite{Guy2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The Spanish `lbx` file is up to date, and everything in general works as expected.

edit:

I followed the instructions given below (refer to Alan Munn's answer) but it turns out I was doing in the wrong place. After I created the proper local texmf structure to host the renewed file where it should be, everything is working as expected. Thank you very much for the expertise!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx and thanks for adding a nice minimal example. What happens if you add `\setcounter{smartand}{0}` after the `\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish-apa}` declaration?

Comment: Nothing changes, no matter where I place it.

Comment: Ok, but actually the setting that `spanish-apa.lbx` uses is `0` which means all 'y' and 'e' get replaced by '&'.  So this is the expected behaviour.  Do you want to get 'y' and 'e' instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default setting for the `spanish-apa` style is that all 'and' gets replaced by &, i.e., it will not be realized as 'y' or 'e'.

For reasons I don't quite understand, changing the value of the counter anywhere has no effect.  I think this is due to the following description in the `biblatex` documentation about how localization files are loaded:

> All localization modules are loaded on demand in the document body.

So if I make a local copy of `spanish-apa.lbx` and comment out the `\setcounter{smartand}{0}` line, I can then change the value of the counter in the preamble and things work as expected (0= always '&', 1= 'y' or 'e' depending on context, 2=always 'y', 3=always 'e').

### Simple solution

The simple solution in Ulrike's answer is probably the easiest to implement:

```
\begin{document}
\setcounter{smartand}{1}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
```

### More permanent solution

So for the moment (unless someone can explain how to overcome the behaviour) you will need to make a local copy of `spanish-apa.lbx` with the `\setcounter` line commented out and then set the value of `smartand` yourself in the preamble.

To make a local copy of the `.lbx` file, it's preferable to rename it to something else so that you remain aware that you are using a modified copy of it.   The copied file should reside either in the same folder as your `.tex` file (if you are only doing this once), or in your local `texmf` folder, inside `texmf/tex/latex/biblatex`.  Then instead of loading `spanish-apa` you load your renamed copy.  Here's an example of what your document would look like.  I've named the local copy `smartand-spanish-apa`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{smartand-spanish-apa}
\setcounter{smartand}{3} % 0, 1, 2 or 3

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Guy2010,
Author = {Some Guy and Another Dude},
Publisher = {A Publisher},
Title = {A reference book to everything},
Year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Localisation is a headache. \parencite{Guy2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, while setting the value to 1, 2 or 3 works for the citation, the reference is [duplicating the surname of the last author.](http://i.imgur.com/hh5dPTS.png)

Comment: Yes, I got that once, but can't reproduce it. Try deleting all your aux files and recompiling.

Comment: Done. Problem persists on my end.

Comment: @absay Strange. I have changed the counter to all the values and it works fine.

Comment: Sorry for the question but when you say "make a local copy" you mean I have to copy the contents of `spanish-apa.lbx` into the preamble of my tex file?

Comment: @absay No. Make a copy of the file `spanish-apa.lbx` and (preferably) rename it to `smartand-spanish-apa.lbx` and place it either in the same folder as your `.tex` file or in your local `texmf` directory in `texmf/tex/latex/biblatex`.  Then edit *that* file, commenting out the `\setcounter` command. I've added this to my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25536/discussion-between-absay-and-alan-munn).

Answer (score 3):

The smartand value is used in spanish.lbx which is loaded by spanish-apa.lbx. So you don't have a chance to change it. But you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}
 %reactivate smartand:
\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}
    {\setcounter{smartand}{1}% or some other value
     \let\lbx@finalnamedelim=\lbx@es@smartand
     \let\lbx@finallistdelim=\lbx@es@smartand}
\makeatother     
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@book{Guy2010,
Author = {Some Guy and Another Dude},
Publisher = {A Publisher},
Title = {A reference book to everything},
Year = {2010}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
Localisation is a headache. \parencite{Guy2010}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Edit

An alternative is to change the value after the begin of the document and  trigger the reevaluation of the language settings:

```
\begin{document}
\setcounter{smartand}{1}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
```