# biblatex seems to take into account symbols when ordering sameauthor sameyear references

Tags: biblatex, apa7

I have runned into an issue with biblatex-apa where I have multiple references with the same author and year, and in one case its taking the "¿" symbol for ordering the references. The document and a lot of references are in spanish. I have set it up like this, using texstudio and luatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[spanish, mexico]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}  
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}  
\DeclareLanguageMapping{spanish}{spanish-apa}  
\addbibresource{reffinal.bib}  

\makeatletter  
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}  
{\setcounter{smartand}{1}% or some other value  
    \let\lbx@finalnamedelim=\lbx@es@smartand  
    \let\lbx@finallistdelim=\lbx@es@smartand}  
\makeatother      

\begin{document}  
    \printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

And I have some references that are like this:

```
@book{minedu2017a,  
    author = {{Ministerio de Educación}},  
    address = {{Lima}},  
    title = {Programa Curricular de Educación Secundaria},  
    year = {2017},  
    url = {http://www.minedu.gob.pe/curriculo/pdf/programa-curricular-educacion-secundaria.pdf}  
}  

@book{minedu2017b,  
  author = {{Ministerio de Educación}},  
  address = {{Lima}},  
  publisher = {{Oficina de Medición de la Calidad de los Aprendizajes}},  
  title = {¿Qué sucede con los aprendizajes en la transición de primaria a secundaria?. Una mirada desde la equidad y la eficacia escolar diferenciada},  
  year = {2017},  
  url = {https://umc.minedu.gob.pe/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-los-aprendizajes-en-la-transici%c3%b3n-de-primaria-a-secundaria.pdf}  
}
```

Following APA 7th rules these should be ordered alphabetically omiting words like “A,” “An,” and “The” at the beginning of a reference title, reasonably this also excludes symbols.
However they turn out in the reverse order putting the reference that starts with "¿" first. I have tried writing this symbol as unicode using \symbol{"00BF} but it still does the same.

Is there a way to overcome this? or to override the citation order?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: + If the answer solved the problem then please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please report any deviations from APA style at https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/issues. The developer can only fix issues if he gets to know about them.

You can ignore leading punctuation for sorting in title fields with `\DeclareNosort` as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish, mexico]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareNosort{
  \nosort{setnames}{\regexp{\p{General_Category=Punctuation}}}
  \nosort{settitles}{\regexp{\A\p{General_Category=Punctuation}+}}
  \nosort{settitles}{\regexp{\A(?:The|An|A)\s+}}
}

\makeatletter
\DefineBibliographyExtras{spanish}
{\setcounter{smartand}{1}% or some other value
    \let\lbx@finalnamedelim=\lbx@es@smartand
    \let\lbx@finallistdelim=\lbx@es@smartand}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{minedu2017a,
  author  = {{Ministerio de Educación}},
  address = {{Lima}},
  title   = {Programa Curricular de Educación Secundaria},
  year    = {2017},
  url     = {http://www.minedu.gob.pe/curriculo/pdf/programa-curricular-educacion-secundaria.pdf}
}
@book{minedu2017b,
  author    = {{Ministerio de Educación}},
  address   = {{Lima}},
  publisher = {{Oficina de Medición de la Calidad de los Aprendizajes}},
  title     = {¿Qué sucede con los aprendizajes en la transición de primaria a secundaria?. Una mirada desde la equidad y la eficacia escolar diferenciada},
  year      = {2017},
  url       = {https://umc.minedu.gob.pe/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Qu%c3%a9-sucede-con-los-aprendizajes-en-la-transici%c3%b3n-de-primaria-a-secundaria.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  Lorem \autocite{minedu2017a,minedu2017b}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: First "P" then "Q"]

The default `\DeclareNosort` in `biblatex-apa` v9.16 (2022/06/22) is ([`apa.bbx`, ll. 264-267](https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/9eb931bdedc36eb261b096e9ff014a5283dff5d7/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/bbx/apa.bbx#L264-L267))

```
\DeclareNosort{
  \nosort{setnames}{\regexp{\p{General_Category=Punctuation}}}
  \nosort{settitles}{\regexp{\A(?:The|An|A)\s+}}
}
```

Comment: +1 Amazing, could you please comment a bit in the part between makeatletter?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Well, it was there already, but I think it is supposed to turn off the "&" for "and" in `biblatex-apa` and use Spanish "y" and "e" (depending on the following word).

Comment: yes, the makeatletter part was for changing & to "y" , I think I took it from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253723/biblatex-apa-not-replacing-ampersand-for-citations-and-references-with-spanish-o

Comment: Thanks, my bad!

Comment: @moewe incredible, it worked like a charm, thanks a lot for this, also yes I was about to post it to their github but found in some cases they refered to here to find some answer first. To expand on your response, and until APA 7th is released in spanish, a useful augmentation for bilingual references would be  \DeclareNosort{
 \nosort{setnames}{\regexp{\p{General_Category=Punctuation}}}
 \nosort{settitles}{\regexp{\A\p{General_Category=Punctuation}+}}
 \nosort{settitles}{\regexp{\A(?:The|An|A|El|La|Los|Las)\s+}}
}